# Rotate Banner ads while changing orientation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rotation, ads

I'm using a video activity,where i have placed a banner.It's good enough at the portrait view.But i would like to rotate the ad in the landscape view.

I'm using AirPush Sdk.
Here is code through i have loaded the banner.

```
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void DynamicBannerAd() {
    layout = new LinearLayout(videoplayer.this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
    videoplayer.this.addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    adView = new AdView(videoplayer.this, AdView.BANNER_TYPE_IN_APP_AD,
            AdView.PLACEMENT_TYPE_INTERSTITIAL, false, false,
            AdView.ANIMATION_TYPE_LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // set Cannback listener for Dynamic Banner
    adView.setAdListener(this);
}
```

I'm adding an example image of what i need...

[Ad Rotation Example Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Ew1tZBfzHQbUt1U3VmT3N4RzQ/view?usp=sharing)

Can someone help me to know,is there any possible way to rotate the banner.
The Airpush SDK seems to be don't have a leaderboard ad.so i'm in need to rotate this banner ad.

Comment: Have you tried google's ADMOB for your ads, it is very simple to use and automatically loads ads when device is rotated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.No, I didn't tried google's ADMOB still now.I have added a sample image with my question.can you please check and tell me ,is that possible in google's ADMOB.

Comment: i think the way you required rotation is not possible with ADMOB, but if you want to do as per your requirement then you can rotate the container in which your adview resides. In your case you are creating a linearlayout and adding adview in it, so try to rotate that linearlayout, it may help

Comment: Share your manifest file....

Comment: hey, @Dhiya have you find any solution on this, I have the same requirement.